# What does it mean Sed –I s/ONBOOT=no/ONBOOT=yes/ /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3

Tags: centos, sed

Please explain the command `sed –I s/ONBOOT=no/ONBOOT=yes/ /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`. What does it mean/do?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean this:

```
sed –i 's/ONBOOT=no/ONBOOT=yes/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
```

(`sed` has no switch called `-I`)

The command means change "in place" (`-i`) the string `ONBOOT=no` into `ONBOOT=yes` in the file `ifcfg-enp0s3`

From `man sed` (GNU `sed`):

```
   -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

          edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

Comment: Sorry it is syntax error by the way thank you so much your quick respond

Answer (score 0):

It will replace in the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` the `ONBOOT=no` with `ONBOOT=yes`.

Feel free to read more about `sed` 
[here](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9rsH7o9DQAhXESBQKHWS9BaAQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grymoire.com%2FUnix%2FSed.html&usg=AFQjCNFVz9uMU4MPn6TOSoCe4Uqv6qmlIg&sig2=OZ9hIXDq3QqaBu6z748YOQ) for example.

Answer (score 0):

After you reboot your PC/server boot proccess will try to set ip address on enp0s3 adapter.

But "-I" should be lowercase "-i". Probably typo.